# Does the formula argument of geom_smooth mirror whats in aes()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot for a logarithmic relationship between variable growth_rate and tenure:

```
pdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = log(TENURE), y = GROWTH_RATE)) +
  geom_point(color = 'gray', alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ x')
```

[image]

But the geom_smooth appears to fit better with:

```
pdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = log(TENURE), y = GROWTH_RATE)) +
  geom_point(color = 'gray', alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ log(x)')
```

[image]

Which plot is correct? Which plot shows a smooth fit line based on a linear model with formula `y ~ log(TENURE)`?

Comment: Side note: Is TENURE in weeks? Otherwise I don't understand how you'd have data with log(TENURE) being 7. Implies >1000 max value for TENURE.

Comment: Hi Jon, It's in days here

Comment: This is at least partly a question about the patterns in your data, which you didn't include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your underlying growth rate varies with the log of the log of tenure. Here's some sample data with that "log of log" relationship:

```
tibble(TENURE = runif(1E4, min = 7, max = 1000),
       GROWTH_RATE = rnorm(1E4, mean = 1, sd = 0.1) * log(log(TENURE))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(log(TENURE), GROWTH_RATE)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3, color = "gray50") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ x')
```

Plotting growth against the log results in a loose fit like your first one. Note that the `lm` is using the transformed values from your `x` and `y` mapping, so we can see that it is using `log(TENURE)` for `x`. (See bottom for a confirmation of that.)

[image]

But modeling against the log of the log of tenure is a better fit. Here, when we use `y ~ log(x)`, it means `y ~ log( [log(TENURE)] )` since x is globally mapped in `ggplot(aes(...))` to relate to the log of TENURE.

```
 ... + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ log(x)')
```

[image]

If instead the original relationship had been a good fit for `y ~ log(x)`, like the different generated data here, your first `lm` would have matched better:

```
tibble(TENURE = runif(1E4, min = 7, max = 1000),
       GROWTH_RATE = rnorm(1E4, mean = 1, sd = 0.1) * log(TENURE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(log(TENURE), GROWTH_RATE)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3, color = "gray50") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y ~ x')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer Jon. Just curious as a follow up - have you encountered log(log(x)) models before? Is this a 'normal' thing?!

Comment: Good question beyond my experience. I saw a few potentially relevant links on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494559/what-is-the-mathematical-meaning-of-when-two-variables-retain-a-non-linear-relat/548507#548507 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255920/what-distribution-to-fit-if-the-log-of-log-is-still-convex